# SVG Rotate does not work on IE - Codepen works perfectly on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css-transforms, keyframe

Rotate function works fine on all browsers except IE.

Comment: the problem is that IE hasn't changed in 6 years - and even 6 years ago it was far from being compatible with the state of play in other browsers - either forget IE or write from scratch for IE only ... or, learn how to write cross browser compatible code - bit don't expect someone to write it for you

Comment: Have you seen what codepen does when you go to it in IE?? "Unsupported Browser" ... so, even the website you're putting your code on doesn't support the browser!!! Kill IE now - I mean, nothing is displayed at all in IE - so how can you say your code doesn't work

Comment: `\`rotate${currPos}to${newPos}\`` --- will never work in IE ... try using something like babeljs to transpile your javascript to something that at least runs on IE

Comment: rotate is undefined every time you click ... I think the battle here is that codepen doesn't work well with IE, so you'll need to debug your code on your server, and determine which parts of your code are simply not supported in IE at all (anything JS2015 or later, like template literals for example) and write your code to IE's standards, or use a transpiler for the JS code to produce code that has the possibility of running in IE

Answer (score 0):

You use `clipPath` on the `<polygon>`, but **clipPath animations** are [not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility). As far as I know, IE supports animation with programatically scripting. For more information, you could refer to the MSDN document: [Basic SVG animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg193979(v=vs.85)).

Here is [an article](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/01/14/cross-browser-animated-image-masking-even-in-ie-using-polyclip-js/) about using **polyClips.js** to make cross-browser animation, you could also check it to try the library as a workaround.